# What is a Contradicting Word™?

Tags: word, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Contradicting Word™. If a word doesn't conform to a special rule, I call it an Agreeable Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule:

[image: Words]

And here is a CSV version for analysis:

> Error: 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: To the solver: Please explain why there is no CSV version...

Comment: Relevant: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42124/what-is-a-shy-word?rq=1

Comment: @greenturtle3141, yes that is relevant...

Comment: Seems to me to be a duplicate of half of this: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41789/what-is-a-mostly-ruddy-word

Comment: The "Method Not Allowed" gag seems out of place here, since the image *also* doesn't have the words in a relevant case.  I.e., font-dependence is trumped by the all-uppercase image.

Comment: @DanRussell, the Method not Allowed bit, was to tell you that it doesn't work in all fonts.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Right, but you didn't give us any fonts that it *does* work in.

Comment: @DanRussell, yes I did, the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Maria's answer, but not quite.

A Contradicting word

> when printed in lower case, begins with a letter that has an ascender. b, d, f, h, k, l have ascenders. Though t breaks above the x-height line, it is not said to have an ascender.
>
>  Some fonts have a higher ascender height than cap height. So, what might appear contradictory about a Contradicting word, therefore, is that in some fonts it is taller in lower case than in upper case.

An Agreeable word

> when printed in lower case, has no ascenders.

As BeastlyGerbil put it,

> A Contradicting word is contradictory because the 'lower' case is actually taller than the 'upper' case. 
> Whereas agreeable words follow normal "uppercase is taller" standard. 
> The CSV version is unavailable because the font in the > has same height capitals

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

> Contradictory words contain letters that are ascending above the row in lowercase. i.e., b, d, f, h, k, l. However, 't' is contained in both types of words. So perhaps the rule is a bit different.

Another observation:

> All Contradictory words start with an ascending letter in lowercase. None of the Agreeable words does.
>  Thus, a word may be Contradictory if in lowercase starts with a letter that is as high as a letter in upper case. But that's a stretch.

About the CSV version:

> Not really sure, as in upper case it is not that obvious anyway. But it was a hint for me to analyze the words/letters in CSV format - both in uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the only letter that goes below the line in contradicting words is "y". Not sure if it's relevant or not, though

Comment: @Kiwi ufortunately not